# Closing just CSVs

Tags: excel, powershell

How can I close a specific Excel workbook in PowerShell?

I have a script that opens 4 CSV files and an XLS file and manipulates some data. I am having a problem closing the CSV files and leaving the XLS file open.

I have tried `$xl.workbooks.close()` but that closes everything. I have tried `$file.close()` but still no luck. Also tried to open the workbooks like this:

```psh
$xl3 = $xl.workbooks.open($wfile) | Out-Null
$xl4 = $xl.workbooks.open($xfile) | Out-Null
$xl5 = $xl.workbooks.open($yfile) | Out-Null
$xl6 = $xl.workbooks.open($zfile) | Out-Null
```

And then close them

```psh
$xl3.Close()
```

Comment: Remove all those `|Out-Null` and that last method should work. You are redirecting the outputted Workbook object to Null, so nothing is being assigned to `$xl3`. Once the `|Out-Null` is removed you should be able to use the `.Close()` method just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing out-null has resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to close the CSVs with something like this:

```psh
$xl.Workbooks | ? { $_.Name -like '*.csv' } | % {
  $_.Close($false)
}
```

Calling the [`Close`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838613.aspx) method with the `SaveChanges` parameter set to `$false` discards all unsaved changes to the file.